# MIPS Assembly remove function for linked list

Tags: mips

I am having trouble writing a remove function for linked list that takes in two parameters, the address of the first node, and the data to be removed from the list. I am first unsure how I am supposed to implement this non recursively.

Comment: Can you post what you already tried and what challenges are you facing ?

Comment: My first challenge is getting the address of the first node. I am unsure how to get the first node to send it as a parameter